# "various" courteous manners instead of "many" courteous manners?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Below is the sentence which was given in my grammar-correction class. It was taught that **many** should be replaced into **various**. However, I totally have no idea why it is so.

"Since about the first century, Arawak Indians' **many** courteous manners had made them stand out from other tribes."

would you explain the reason to me? Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Both adjectives are awkward. And the Arawak tribe in Pre-Columbian Puerto Rico stood out as aggressive and warring, not well-mannered.

Comment: _Manners_, in the sense of social deportment, is a plural mass noun, like _oats_. It takes a plural verb, but it can't be modified by words like _various_ that indicate individuality instead of generality.

Comment: @Yosef 'Many' at least is almost universally agreed to be a quantifier (a subclass of determiners, not adjectives). 'Various' here is an adjective, though not always (see Lexico). // I'll take your stance on the history involved as correct, given the standard of the question.

Comment: The bottom line: neither the quantifier _many_ nor the (here) adjective _various_ should be used with the non-count usage of _manners_ in the sentence. The fact that it is a _plural-form_ non-count usage (compare *many clothes / *various clothes; contrast many dogs / various dogs) does not license using 'many' or individualising adjectives like 'assorted'.

Comment: It isn’t a good sentence, so it is difficult to answer the question as put. Neither “many” nor “various” are correct. No modifier is called for.

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. Along with grammatical advice, you taught me new cultural awareness. Since I am new to this platform, pls tell me how to take a next step for my question above. Should I "close"? ( is this what is called in this platform?